# Peewee async unexpected keyword when updating

Tags: python, asynchronous, peewee

While using peewee async, got an error when trying to update an object:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/models/module.py", line 74, in run
    await self._stage_alert_attach(target_alert)
  File "./src/models/module.py", line 293, in _stage_alert_attach
    await target_alert.attach(unattached_issues)
  File "./src/models/alert.py", line 127, in attach
    await issue.attach(self)
  File "./src/models/issue.py", line 81, in attach
    await self.async_save()
  File "./src/models/base.py", line 40, in async_save
    return await self._manager.update(self, only=self.dirty_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/peewee_async.py", line 227, in update
    query = obj.update(**field_dict).where(obj._pk_expr())
TypeError: update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'alert_id'
```

I can't figure out what's happening because the field is defined in the base class:

```
class BaseIssue(BaseModel):
    # Database fields
    id = peewee.PrimaryKeyField()
    module_id = peewee.IntegerField()
    model = peewee.CharField(index=True)
    model_id = peewee.CharField(index=True)
    status = peewee.CharField(index=True)
    metadata = JSONField()
    alert_id = peewee.IntegerField(null=True)
    created_at = peewee.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    solved_at = peewee.DateTimeField(null=True)
    expired_at = peewee.DateTimeField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        def db_table_func(model_cls): return "Issues"
```

Also tried to use `alert` instead of `alert_id` and using it as a foreign key, but got the same error (now with the alert keyword).

I think there might be a problem with inheritance, as this base class is inherited to create an DefaultIssue class that will be inherited again. For some reason the `update()` method is not expecting this parameter.

Here's a print of the object `__dict__` and fields right before the `self.async_save()` call:

```
>>> obj.__dict__

{
  "_data": {
    "created_at": datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 10, 17, 6, 8, 47075),
    "id": 2,
    "module_id": 3,
    "model": "transaction",
    "model_id": "23765771",
    "status": "active",
    "metadata": {
      "transaction_id": 23765771,
      "boleto_url": None,
      "boleto_barcode": None
    },
    "alert_id": None,
    "solved_at": None,
    "expired_at": None
  },
  "_dirty": set(),
  "_obj_cache": {},
  "_logger": <Logger Issue 2 (INFO)>
}

>>> obj._meta.fields

{
  "id": <peewee.PrimaryKeyField object at 0x7f49fdb2e198>,
  "module_id": <peewee.IntegerField object at 0x7f49fdb2e3c8>,
  "model": <peewee.CharField object at 0x7f49fdb2e710>,
  "model_id": <peewee.CharField object at 0x7f49fdb2e7f0>,
  "status": <peewee.CharField object at 0x7f49fdb2e860>,
  "metadata": <playhouse.postgres_ext.JSONField object at 0x7f49fdb2e8d0>,
  "alert_id": <peewee.IntegerField object at 0x7f49fdb2e940>,
  "created_at": <peewee.DateTimeField object at 0x7f49fdb2e9b0>,
  "solved_at": <peewee.DateTimeField object at 0x7f49fdb2ea20>,
  "expired_at": <peewee.DateTimeField object at 0x7f49fdb2ea90>
}
```

If there's any more information I can provide, ask please. I don't know what to do anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'm so stupid. Just noticed I've overriden the update method.